# Does Solr data import handler support custom variables?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I currently have an issue with my data import handler where `${dataimporter.last_index_time}` is not granular enough to capture two events that happen within a second of each other, leading to issues where a record is skipped over in my database.

I am thinking to replace `last_index_time` with a simple atomically incrementing value as opposed to a datetime, but in order to do that I need to be able to set and read custom variables through solr that can be referenced in my `data-config.xml` file.

**Alternatively**, if I could find some way to *set* `dataimporter.last_index_time`, that would work just as well as I could ensure that the last_index_time is less than the newly-committed rows (and more importantly, that it is set from the same clock).

Does Solr support this?

Comment: with incrementing values, the newly added rows can be handled/ imported.. how could updates on already existing rows be imported?

Comment: I would update those rows' incremental values just the same as if they were new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it does

Long answer:

At work I'm passing parameters in request ([DataImportHandler: Accessing request parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Accessing_request_parameters)) with default values set in handler (solrconfig.xml)

To sum up:

You can do use something like that in data-config.xml

```
${dataimporter.request.your_variable}
```

With request:

```
/dataimport&command=delta-import&clean=false&commit=true&your_variable=123
```

Comment: Excellent, that looks like it might be exactly what I need. I will take a look at it Monday. Cheers. :)

Comment: What if i have more than one solr master node how should i handle this.