# Add a cron job to one entity at a time

Tags: solr, cron

I have two entities in data-config.xml file. I want to run a cron job for each entity at different frequencies. Is it possible to have different times for each entity? Or will it always make two requests when there are two entities when import is done using cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using

DIH commands are sent to Solr via an HTTP request. 
The following operations are supported.

Only the SqlEntityProcessor supports delta imports.

For example: http://localhost:8983/solr/dih/dataimport?command=delta-import.

This command supports the same clean, commit, optimize and debug parameters as full-import command described below.

**entity** 
The name of an entity directly under the  tag in the configuration file. Use this to execute one or more entities selectively.

Multiple "**entity**" parameters can be passed on to run multiple entities at once. If nothing is passed, all entities are executed.

For example:

http://localhost:8983/solr/dih/dataimport?command=delta-import&entity=YOUR_ENTIY_NAME

**Read more**

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html

Comment: It is working if I run it. But, using the cron job both the entities are being executed.

Comment: I gave a cron job in this way */1 * * * * curl http://localhost:8983/solr/sample/dataimport?command=full-import&entity=test&clean=false
yet, it executes the other entity as well.

Comment: As, I'm increasing the data the cron job is failing. It is again executing both the entities. If one entity is delta and the other is full it is working, however, it both the entities are full import params, specifying the entity is not making any difference. Is there anything which can be done?

Comment: @bhargavaravalikoganti This is really odd, this should work! There is another way of doing it by passing custom variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240826/does-solr-data-import-handler-support-custom-variables In the query you could specify a condition.

Comment: I do not have any custom variables to pass. The problem is, it is working fine if I run it direct in a browser, but using a cron job it is executing both the entities.

Comment: Cron job is not executing the params after command=full-import in the http request. I just checked out in terminal using wget. Is there anything which can be done?